# Count(*) Vs. Max(Id)

Tags: mysql

If have a table where I do bulk imports from CSV files.

First column is the Id field with autoincrement.
What bothers me is:
When I do a

```
Select count(*)
```

And a

```
Select max(Id)
```

I get different values. I would have expected those to be identical ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you inserting into the `id` column with values or not?

Comment: No. I just let the autoincrement do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert 10 rows, delete 5, then insert 10 more then your `COUNT(*)` will not match `MAX(id)`.

You can also insert an `id` way ahead of where it should be, like in an empty table `INSERT ... (id) VALUES (9000000)` will kick up your `MAX(id)` significantly despite having only 1 row.

Rolled-back transactions can also interfere with this.

If you want to know the next increment, check the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, but be aware that this is only a guess, the actual value used may differ by the time you actually get around to inserting.

If you want them to match then you need to:

- Start with a table where `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`, as in it's either brand new or has been cleared with `TRUNCATE`.
- Insert using auto-generated `id` values as one transaction, or as a series of transactions where all of them have been fully committed.

Comment: Ah interesting. So what's the most accurate way to see how many actual data rows I have ?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is the only accurate way. `MAX(id)` tells you nothing more than the maximum `id` value.